# Move uploaded content automatically from one node to another

Tags: 7, nodes, redirection, files

Is it possible post `images/text` on a different page other than the one being uploaded?

I have an `insert` page where users can add `images/text` but I want whatever they post to go on another page automatically ('things' page) sorted by the most recent first. I only want to keep the 'insert' page as an 'insert' and without content!

Answer (score 1):

Content in Drupal is organized in "[nodes](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/node)":

> A node is any piece of individual content, such as a page, poll, article, forum topic, or a blog entry. Comments are not stored as nodes but are always connected to one.

So you'll always have a "page" or whatever your content type is named, to store and edit the content. But you don't need to show these pages necessarily to the visitors or users of that site.

You should take a look into [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module, which will enable you to create (another sort of) "pages" that automatically collect content from "nodes" according to the rules and filters that you have definded for it.